# apache NiFi 1.13.2 ListenWebsocket not working

Tags: java, websocket, apache-nifi

I download NiFi 1.13.2 and make simple processes,
but ListenWebsocket process was not working.

Processes and settings is below.
</pre[enter image [description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPE0R.png) here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WfmO.png)>

Http response is below.

```
    HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
    Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store 
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1 
    Content-Length: 4385 
    Connection: close 
    Server: Jetty(9.4.38.v20210224) 
    Handshake status 500 Server Error
```

nifi-app.log error is below.

```
    2021-10-26 14:11:22,845 INFO [pool-20-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
    2021-10-26 14:11:22,861 INFO [pool-20-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Successfully checkpointed FlowFile Repository with 0 records in 0 milliseconds
    2021-10-26 14:11:30,477 WARN [qtp1691911352-55] o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler.ROOT unavailable
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory
            at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory$Loader.load(WebSocketServletFactory.java:54)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet.init(WebSocketServlet.java:140)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:624)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:478)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:751)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:279)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory$Loader.load(WebSocketServletFactory.java:48)
            ... 26 common frames omitted
        2021-10-26 14:11:30,481 WARN [qtp1691911352-55] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel /test
        javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory
            at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet.init(WebSocketServlet.java:147)
            at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:624)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:478)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare(ServletHolder.java:751)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:279)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory
            at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory$Loader.load(WebSocketServletFactory.java:54)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet.init(WebSocketServlet.java:140)
            ... 25 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory$Loader.load(WebSocketServletFactory.java:48)
            ... 26 common frames omitted
        2021-10-26 14:11:42,864 INFO [pool-20-thread-1] o.a.n.c.r.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository Initiating checkpoint of FlowFile Repository
```

Tell me how to correct settings or correct usage

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug ([Apache jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8347)).

Try using a different version. In 1.15.0 it works.